# How to add custom error message with reload button in WebView Android?

Tags: android, webview

Hi guys i am creating a web view app for my site 
the problem is whenever the internet is not available webview shows web page not available

But what i want is to Display a Message &  a reload button saying 'You need to be connected to internet to use this app press reload after turning on internet' . Thanks in advance.

Comment: webview.loadUrl("about:blank");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the net connectivity on opening the webView.

Here I am providing you the method for the same.

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Here I am sharing the method for the same.

```
public void showAlert(String msg) {

          ContextThemeWrapper themedContext;
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
           themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);
          } else {
           themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(
             context,
             android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
          }

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    themedContext);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg).setPositiveButton("Reload",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //Call webview again.
                                dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
```

call this method `showAlert("You need to be connected to internet to use this app press reload after turning on internet")`

Comment: But how to show the warning ('You need to be connected to internet to use this app press reload after turning on internet')  &  the reaoad button?